# more coffeescript array assignment

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following array assignment:

```
advances = if advance == 0 then [advance] else [advance, (0 - advance)]
```

I wonder if there is a more coffeescript way of doing this?

Comment: I guess you could say `is` instead of `==` if you really wanted to. They both mean `===`

Comment: Many people avoid the `is` and use plain old `==`. This way you are more compatible with the majority of developers. I also prefer to use `if object then x else y` (JavaScript's magic check for `"", undefined, false, null, 0`) which works fine in many places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your own proposal is perfectly fine.  It's simple, clear, and pure-functional.

If you think minimizing punctuation is part of the coffeescript way then you could drop the parentheses

```
advances = if advance == 0 then [advance] else [advance, 0 - advance]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
advances = [advance]
advances.push (0 - advance) if advance != 0
```

I think this is a bit more readable. But I guess that a matter of taste.
It also uses coffee-script's nice if-at-the-end feature, which I makes some statements such as this "conditional array growing" more readable (for me at least).

PS: I also changed the `== 0` to `!= 0` to avoid the `unless` statement. It just confuses me when reading code.

PPS: Don't put everything on one line just for the sake of it (even if is coffee-script is good at that). Always think of the most readable (and well performing) code.

Comment: I am not sure the `unless` is a problem, I actually like it. Also, the use of `is` helps the reading :)

`advances.push (0 - advance) unless advance is 0`

Comment: No I don't like that way. It is already hard to tell my colleagues about coffee-script anyway. And adding new words for very common things such as `==` and `if` just opens the door hell. ;)

Comment: Yeah you've got a point here. Not a real problem anyway, your answer is good as it is.

Comment: IMO splitting the same piece of code as in question into four line gives actually something cleaner and more readable than what I and you proposed in our answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're perhaps thinking about list comprehensions, but I can't imagine how to utilize them here.  I believe you'd get better result utilizing underscore.js (or some other library providing collection utilities):

```
advances = _.uniq([advance, (0 - advance)])
```

http://underscorejs.org/#uniq